# java mongodb findOne with long type _id

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

ids in my mongodb collection is in the following format

```
  "_id" : NumberLong("502434721406525440"),
```

and I'm trying to execute findOne method of mongo to retrieve an item with a desired id. However, I couldn't manage with the following code piece.

```
@Autowired
private MyItemRepository myRepo;

public MyItem getItemById(String itemId) {
    return myRepo.findOne(itemId);
}
```

and MyItem class is as follows:

```
public class MyItem{
    @Id
    private final long itemId;

    //and some other fields

    //and getter methods

}
```

and my repository is as follows:

```
public interface MyItemRepository extends
    PagingAndSortingRepository<MyItem, String> {

}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it could have to do with string versus number types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding findOne method solved my problem. I can help anyone having the same problem.

```
mongoTemplate.findOne(
            Query.query(Criteria.where("itemId").is(Long.decode(itemId))),
            MyItem.class, collectionName);
```